# vb.net how to set combobox from access query

Tags: vb.net, ms-access-2007

I have a code like this (still not finished because I don't know the access connection setting)

```
 Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim da As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim sql As String
    Dim golmin As String
    golmin = ComboBox1.SelectedText

    con.ConnectionString = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source = C:/Users/RUMAH49/Documents/Visual Studio 2008/Projects/Project-Christian/Project-Christian/MineralDB.mdb"

    con.Open()

    sql = "SELECT [Nama Mineral] FROM MsMineral WHERE [Golongan Mineral] LIKE '" + golmin + "'"
    da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con)


End Sub
```

I want to populate the combobox2 list with the query above. How do I do that? Is this connection incorrect or do I still have to use the Dataset wizard?

Comment: Connection strings can be got from: http://connectionstrings.com, eg `Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\mydatabase.mdb;` Why have you got slashes rather than backslashes? Your path is far too long for MS Access to work well.

Comment: @Remou +1 for noticing the slashes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are trying to connect to Access 2007 then you need to use a different provider

**Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0**

please refer to this link [here](http://www.connectionstrings.com/providers/ace-oledb-12-0)

Comment: Jet 4.0 provider is correct for mdb. You only need Ace provider for accdb, which the OP is not using.

Comment: I switched my access to accdb (later version of access). It worked, though I still didn't figure out what went wrong. anyway thanks

Comment: I'm glad it helped. Enjoy!